# How do I control the Com Port under Firemonkey?

Tags: firemonkey

I am developing in Firemonkey and need to access the com port (serial port) for an OSX application. There is a component by Winsoft, but this limits the user to standard baud rates. I need to set this to 48000 (not 4800). It was straightforward using WinAPI but I am not sure of the commands I can now use. Any advice, anyone?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?